# How to reference previously added components in Swing with MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

So my end goal with what I am creating is to have a JPanel with nice tabbed buttons (think JTabbedPane except people will *like* how it looks).

To accomplish this I create a JPanel, then I have a method called `addContent(String name, JPanel jp)`. The point of this method is to... add new Content. It's basically adding a tab and JPanel to the mix.

And that's where I need your help. I want to be able to add JButtons ****infinitely**** to my JPanel. I'm using `MigLayout`, and since I'm not too great with it, I came up with this:

```
this.add(button, "w 40%!, h 50!, x 0%, y (0% + last.y2), wrap, id last");
```

It's atrocious, I know. But what it's trying to accomplish is reference the `y2` of the 
previously made button, then set the button 'that is being added' to the 'previously made' button.

Just to clarify, I have set the encompassing JPanel to MigLayout, and this is more of a schematics problem.

Comment: *"(think JTabbedPane except people will **like** how it looks)."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  As an aside: I **like** how the current tabbed pane looks.  Which PLAF, orientation and other settings are you referring to as (implied) people *don't* like it?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Ok. Maybe I assumed too much, but I basically was just trying to get rid of the ugly Windows XP style tabs. I ended up finding a solution though. I'll post a picture on my answer so you can see the 'nicer' ones.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I ended up using was a lot more fundamental. And obvious. But I figure I might as well share it anyway.

```
this.add(button, "w 40%!, h 50!, x 0%, wrap");
```

So basically it'll add buttons all day. Well. Sorta. :D

[image]

This is what my pane ended up looking like. You can basically add buttons to it infinitely, and it's a bit easier on the eyes than good ole JTabbedPanes.